# a network gateway that modifies content - how to do it?

Tags: networking, proxy

I'd like to set up a network gateway that will modify on the fly the code of webpages accessed by users on my LAN. For instance, I'd like to automatically remove ads, suspicious object or iframe tags.

So it's kind of a centralised AdBlock, except I'd like to be able to write my own rules easily.

I'm only interested in open-source solutions for Linux.

(Bonus question: how to combine that with a TLS mitm proxy, so that TLS traffic is also modified. Of course, machines on this LAN will have my private cert.)

EDIT:

Turns out there's a term for that: Content Adaptation. :)

Comment: heres one approach using squid and apache, to turn all the images in a website upside down: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upside-Down-TernetHowTo

Answer (score 0):

Acting as a proxy you can use Squid. You can get this from: http://www.squid-cache.org

As Squid is a proxy server, you can mass block ad servers.

Comment: Why would it be illegal? Companies do it, and so can you. As long as all users consent, I don’t see the legal problem.

Comment: All I'm going to say is that it's illegal to use a SSL proxy where I live.

Comment: If I'm monitoring SSL in my own private network, there's nothing illegal about that.

Comment: there you are, edited

Comment: Yup, I interpreted "block ad servers" as URL blocking, which is not enough.

Squid seems interesting. I just get confused by the "cache" idea, because I want to work on the fly, not cache anything, but never mind. ;)

PS. Sorry to hear you live under such a nasty regime. I checked your profile - Five Eyes - no wonder your freedoms are limited.
(Yes, I'm trolling - just a little bit. ;))

Comment: np, all squid is a proxy/cache server that can save bandwidth, as well as (iirc) SSL snooping. the cache part stops you reloading lots of images, the proxy part doesn't need to be explained

Comment: This is legal in most countries. However, you may get into trouble if you don't declare it. You can get into worse trouble intercepting TLS because if anything goes wrong with a transaction you could end up with the blame.